# I am trying to use circuitikz, but this error pops up whenever I compile

Tags: errors, circuitikz, pgfkeys

I am currently trying to run some examples in the `circuitikz` library, and I keep getting the following error and the document will not compile:

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/circuitikz/label/align' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
```

I don't know if I am missing any essential packages, but I have installed `circuitikz` and `xstring` and I assume that TikZ is part of the TeX distribution I have. (MacTeX 2010) I am compiling my documents with TeXShop on Mac OSX 10.6.8 with that distribution if that helps anyone.

An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{circuitikz} 
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg} 
\title{} 
\author{} 
\date{} 
\begin{document} 
\maketitle 
\begin{circuitikz}[scale =1.2]
\draw (0,0) node[op amp] (opamp {} (opamp.+) 
            node[left] {$v_+$} (opamp.-) 
            node[left] {$v_-$} (opamp.out) 
            node[right] {$v_0$} ;
\end{circuitikz} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can you include a simplest kind of example that you run into errors? It's great benefit to include an example starts with a `\documentclass{...}` gives the example in the document body and end with `\end{document}` such that we see clearly the scope you are working in.

Comment: Here is what I was trying to run.

`\documentclass{article}`
`\usepackage{amsmath}`
`\usepackage{mathtools}`
`\usepackage{graphicx}`
`\usepackage{circuitikz}`
`\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}`
`\title{}`
`\author{}`
`\date{}`
`\begin{document}`
`\maketitle`
`\begin{circuitikz}[scale =1.2]\ draw`
`(0,0) node[op amp] (opamp {}`
`(opamp.+) node[left] {$v_+$}`
`(opamp.-) node[left] {$v_-$}`
`(opamp.out) node[right] {$v_0$}`
`;\end{circuitikz}`
`\end{document}`

EDIT: I have no idea how to get the lines of code to separate in a comment. I'll try to get this example in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok seems you're missing a parenthesis...

Here is the partial working code (related to the circuit) :

```
\begin{circuitikz}[scale =1.2]
\draw (0,0) node[op amp] (opamp) {} (opamp.+) 
            node[left] {$v_+$} (opamp.-) 
            node[left] {$v_-$} (opamp.out) 
            node[right] {$v_0$} ;
\end{circuitikz}
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: I get the same error, but now it looks as if I just press enter a couple of times in the console that pops up whenever I compile something it compiles as normal in spite of that error. I suppose it's just a fluff error that will make my document compiling times annoying, but I suppose that's better than not having any circuits compile at all. Thank you so much for your help!